# POST form Angular2

Tags: node.js, rest, angular, authentication, post

I'm trying to execute a login form with Angular2 with NodeJS API as a backend server.

I cant't post any request to the API.
Here it's my front code example:

```
private authenticate_url = "Server_URL:PORT/authenticate";
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log("Username : "+username+" Password : "+password);
    return this.http.post(this.authenticate_url, { username, password }, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Either when I'm checking network activity, no POST request was executed.

Comment: inspect your browser f12, check what is it logging.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: this.http.post(...).map(...).catch is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .subscribe() method of RxJS in order to actually execute the query, so you need to write it like this:

```
return this.http.post(this.authenticate_url, { username, password }, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError)
                .subscribe((queryResult) => {console.log(queryResult)})
```

Or you can do it outside your function like:

```
login("baksdasd", "asfasfasdf").subscribe((queryResult) => {console.log(queryResult)})
```

You also need to import the operators that you use:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Here you have a detailed tutorial to solve any other problem that you may have: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Comment: I cant use the subscribe function because i am using Observable. In this case, I think the correct way is to use "map" instead of "subscribe".

Using your code, I had this error : 
ERROR in /home/iot/ng2-admin/src/app/_services/authentication.service.ts (25,18): Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you need to subscribe to an Observable. So if you return it in your function, you will need to subscribe wherever you want to use it, like I showed you in the second case. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: The missing thing in my code was to subscribe to the Observable ! All I need was that. Thanks Jesusbotella